# How can I fix a segmentation fault caused by a summation function I am trying to call? C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create functions to be called later in the program that would essentially perform the operation I need later. I have 9 functions being called that include: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, modulus, square root, absolute value, power, and summation. For the first 8 operations I have had no issue changing the modules into functions. However, because there is no symbol in C++ for summation I have run into an issue trying to convert its module into a function, the program allows me to run it and if I run all other operations it is fine but as soon as I attempt to call my summation function I am given a segmentation fault. My code looks like:

```
//summation function
int summ(int a)
{
    return summ(a);
    {
        int summ=0;
        int n=a;

        for (summ=0; summ<n; summ++)
        {
            summ += summ;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or advice would be appreciated. I can include any other information needed, thank you.

Comment: You have a stack overflow caused by infinite recursion. `int summ(int a)
{

return summ(a);`

Comment: Your loop is unreachable code, but your summ is being doubled each iteration and doing double duty as the loop index variable.  So that loop is trying to compute an exponential, except summ starts at zero so it says at zero.  Is this intentional?  If all you want to do is sum the integers from 1 to a, consider Gauss's formula.

Comment: Then you also should probably not name your variable the same as the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function has a return statement as its first line. Nothing else is executed. So you have infinite recursion. It's as if the function were:

```
int summ(int a)
   return summ(a);
}
```